# how to match pandas dataframes with different temporal resolution

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

[image]

I have two dataframes, **visitors** stores *daily* visitor numbers and **temperatures** stores the *weekly* temperature values.

---

[image]

I want to merge these two dataframes, I tried to hardcode for interpolating temperature values between weeks but couldn't do it. How can I create daily temperature values like shown below and merge those dataframes without any NaN values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) of `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random((29, 1)),
    index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=29, freq='D'),
    columns=['visitors_per_day']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random((5, 1)),
    index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', periods=5, freq='7D'),
    columns=['temperature_per_week'],
)

df3 = df1.join(df2.resample('D').asfreq().interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2))
```

Here `df3` and a plot of it (`df3.plot(marker='s')`):

```sh
            visitors_per_day  temperature_per_week
2000-01-01          0.010502              0.711920
2000-01-02          0.741374              0.581057
2000-01-03          0.188808              0.469889
2000-01-04          0.455265              0.378416
2000-01-05          0.006640              0.306639
2000-01-06          0.017734              0.254558
2000-01-07          0.561381              0.222172
2000-01-08          0.118478              0.209482
2000-01-09          0.350630              0.216487
```

[image]